# Using PDFBox to merge documents causes strange color inversion

Tags: java, pdf, colors, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to merge all the documents in a directory into one master pdf.  There are letters and Simple Certified Mail labels.  There's a one to one relationship between letters and labels.  The file names are a policy number for the letter and the policy number -L for the label.  When looking in the directory the letters and labels match up so that when the combined document is created the letters and labels are collated.  The merge works perfectly, however the labels come out with a purple background and yellow text.

The letters are created using a pdf template with updatable fields and the labels are created using FileOutputStream.

I wouldn't think this would be an issue because when I view the individual label files they are all black and white as expected.

Has anyone experienced this problem?  If you need code, let me know what you need and I'll paste it in.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bug.  I would advise contacting the good folks at Apache - there's a chance they don't know about it.  (http://pdfbox.apache.org/support.html)

Comment: You may also post a source sample and pdf samples here to reproduce the issue as certain pdfbox developers read here, too.

Comment: I listed it as an issue with Apache.  Thanks guys.  I'll post an answer if this ever gets resolved.  They first said to try 2.0.0 to see if that helps.  We'll see.

Comment: So has it been solved by now?

Comment: I got an email from Apache that said that the issue was closed.